How to attach an Elastic IP to an EC2 instance in Terraform
I am trying to attach an EIP to an EC2 instance that is being deployed with Terraform. The stack has a launch template resource which is defining the instance and also a auto scaling group resource.
I am creating an EIP resource in Terraform and adding the following into the user data to try attach an EIP (since an instance can go down and replaced by ASG, user data makes sense)
EIP_ALLOCATION_ID=$(aws ec2 allocate-address --query 'AllocationId' --output text)
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)

aws ec2 associate-address --instance-id "$INSTANCE_ID" --allocation-id "$EIP_ALLOCATION_ID" --allow-reassociation

The issue I can see on the cloud init log is it fails to go through and says "Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"." This is even tho I am attaching an IAM profile Terraform resource that has the correct permissions.
Any suggestions on getting past this error?

The error is saying that you do not have any AWS credentials to make the request.
The normal way of providing credentials is:

Create an IAM Role
Assign sufficient permissions to the IAM Role so that it can use AssociateAddress (and AllocateAddress if appropriate)
Specify the IAM Role when launching the EC2 instance (see: Add/attach AWS IAM Role to EC2 instance via terraform

Also: Since you want to 'reattach' the Elastic IP address to the new instance, you should presumably only create the Elastic IP address once. You would then run the associate-address command on the new instance, always using the existing Elastic IP address. Therefore, I don't think you should put the allocate-address command in the startup script.
Alternatively: If you are wanting to connect an Amazon Route 53 DNS name to an instance, you could bypass the Elastic IP address altogether and directly update the A-Record directly. See: Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community
